# XSLT: Generating integer IDs and reference them having string keys on the input

Tags: xslt, reference, integer, key, generated

I need to generate integer IDs for products and than reference related products by those integer IDs in the output. On the input I have string keys representing this relationship. Thank you for your help.

Input:

```
<root>
  <products>
    <product>
      <!-- a unique string key of this node between the other product nodes -->
      <stringKey>AppleRef</stringKey>
      <Name>Apple</Name>
      <relatedProducts>
        <!-- a reference to product/StringKey of Orange -->
        <relatedProductStringKey>OrangeRef</relatedProductStringKey>
        <!-- other related products may follow -->
      </relatedProducts>
    </product>
    <product>
      <stringKey>OrangeRef</stringKey>
      <Name>Orange</Name>
      <relatedProducts>
        <relatedProductStringKey>AppleRef</relatedProductStringKey>
      </relatedProducts>
    </product>
  </products>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
  <products>
    <P>
      <ProductInfo>
        <!-- a unique integer ID of this node between the other ProductsInfo nodes -->
        <ProductID>0</ProductID>
        <ProductRef>AppleRef</ProductRef>
        <ProductName>Apple</ProductName>
      </ProductInfo>
      <R>
        <ProductRelatedInfo>

          <!-- a unique integer ID of this node between the other ProductRelatedInfo nodes -->
          <RelatedID>0</RelatedID>

          <!-- a reference to ProductInfo/ProductID of Orange -->
          <RelatedProductID>1</RelatedProductID>

        </ProductRelatedInfo>
        <!-- other related products may follow -->

      </R>
    </P>
    <P>
      <ProductInfo>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductRef>OrangeRef</ProductRef>
        <ProductName>Orange</ProductName>
      </ProductInfo>
      <R>
        <ProductRelatedInfo>
          <RelatedID>1</RelatedID>
          <RelatedProductID>0</RelatedProductID>
        </ProductRelatedInfo>
      </R>
    </P>
  </products>
</root>
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to replace a unique string with a unique numeric string (i.e. an integer)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k because the output format is required by an external application. I need to convert a catalog of products exported from one application to a format for importing the data to another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do using a **key**. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="product" match="product" use="stringKey" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stringKey">
    <ProductID><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::product)"/></ProductID>
    <ProductRef><xsl:value-of select="."/></ProductRef>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="relatedProductStringKey">
    <RelatedProductID><xsl:value-of select="count(key('product', .)/preceding-sibling::product)"/></RelatedProductID>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <products>
      <product>
         <ProductID>0</ProductID>
         <ProductRef>AppleRef</ProductRef>
         <Name>Apple</Name>
         <relatedProducts>
            <RelatedProductID>1</RelatedProductID>
         </relatedProducts>
      </product>
      <product>
         <ProductID>1</ProductID>
         <ProductRef>OrangeRef</ProductRef>
         <Name>Orange</Name>
         <relatedProducts>
            <RelatedProductID>0</RelatedProductID>
         </relatedProducts>
      </product>
   </products>
</root>
```

If you prefer a meaningless, though not necessarily numeric ID, you might prefer the simpler:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="product" match="product" use="stringKey" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stringKey">
    <ProductID><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(..)"/></ProductID>
    <ProductRef><xsl:value-of select="."/></ProductRef>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="relatedProductStringKey">
    <RelatedProductID><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('product', .))"/></RelatedProductID>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The exact result depends on the processor, for example Saxon might return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <products>
      <product>
         <ProductID>d0e3</ProductID>
         <ProductRef>AppleRef</ProductRef>
         <Name>Apple</Name>
         <relatedProducts>
            <RelatedProductID>d0e11</RelatedProductID>
         </relatedProducts>
      </product>
      <product>
         <ProductID>d0e11</ProductID>
         <ProductRef>OrangeRef</ProductRef>
         <Name>Orange</Name>
         <relatedProducts>
            <RelatedProductID>d0e3</RelatedProductID>
         </relatedProducts>
      </product>
   </products>
</root>
```

while libxslt will produce something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <products>
    <product>
      <ProductID>idp116928</ProductID>
      <ProductRef>AppleRef</ProductRef>
      <Name>Apple</Name>
      <relatedProducts>
        <RelatedProductID>idp1506944</RelatedProductID>
      </relatedProducts>
    </product>
    <product>
      <ProductID>idp1506944</ProductID>
      <ProductRef>OrangeRef</ProductRef>
      <Name>Orange</Name>
      <relatedProducts>
        <RelatedProductID>idp116928</RelatedProductID>
      </relatedProducts>
    </product>
  </products>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get integer IDs in XSLT you can use the position of the nodes in the document, which you can get by counting its preceding nodes.

The following stylesheet will produce your desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match product node -->
    <xsl:template match="product">
        <P>
            <ProductInfo>
                <ProductID>
                    <!-- count preceding-sibling products -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::product)"/>
                </ProductID>
                <ProductRef>
                    <xsl:value-of select="stringKey"/>
                </ProductRef>
                <ProductName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                </ProductName>
            </ProductInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="relatedProducts"/>
        </P>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="relatedProducts">
        <R>
            <xsl:for-each select="relatedProductStringKey">
                <!-- apply on product that has a matching stringkey -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/products/product[stringKey=current()]" mode="related">
                    <!-- 
                        RelatedID will be unique within each relatedProducts node, 
                        if you want this to be unique across the document use preceding:: instead 
                    -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="RelatedID" select="count(preceding-sibling::relatedProductStringKey)"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </R>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match product node for related products -->
    <xsl:template match="product" mode="related">
        <xsl:param name="RelatedID"/>
        <ProductRelatedInfo>

            <!-- a unique integer ID of this node between the other ProductRelatedInfo nodes -->
            <RelatedID>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RelatedID"/>
            </RelatedID>

            <!-- a reference to ProductInfo/ProductID of Orange -->
            <RelatedProductID>
                <!-- count preceding-sibling products again -->
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::product)"/>
            </RelatedProductID>

        </ProductRelatedInfo>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for your help, @Tobias. I aplied michael.hor257k's solution, because it looked more readable for me. I am new to XSLT, so I may be wrong. I think your solution is useful for reference, I may apply it later for this or similar problem. If you or someone knows any advantages of this solution over the one I selected, please let me know.